# Marklogic XCC or JAVA/REST

Tags: marklogic

I see marklogic offers various interfaces to communicate with. Considering Java as client application, which of XCC, JAVA/REST is best option to choose.

Am I getting any benefit if I choose XCC over JAVA/REST vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you like XQuery, you should strongly consider XCC, which gives you a straightforward interface for executing XQuery on the server.

Otherwise, you should take a look at the MarkLogic Java API. Features include

- interfaces for building a query and processing the response
- support for bulk write, bulk read, and bulk query
- good integration with Java IO representations via adapters ("handles")
- a POJO-oriented repository interface
- encapsulation of HTTP housekeeping including connection pooling
- installation and execution of server extensions such as transforms and services

If you are ingesting a very large dataset, you should use the mlcp tool for maximum performance.

Down the road, if you start deploying modules to the server, you should take a look at ml-gradle

Hoping that's useful,

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternate perspective -- coding your way into single-vendor lockin isn't a great place to be.

Consider [the XQuery API for Java (XQJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java) as a native-Java interface, inspired by JDBC, with drivers available for numerous database backends, including [a MarkLogic driver](http://xqj.net/marklogic/).

---

XQJ is a fully-featured interface; quoting from [its webpage](http://xqj.net/):

> The XQuery API interface supports
>
> - Executing XQuery against an XML Datasource and processing the results in Java.
> - Binding XQuery variables from Java.
> - Creating Prepared and Adhoc XQuery expressions.
> - Altering XQuery Static and Dynamic Context behaviour.
> - ACID Transactions.
> - XML Processing via StAX, SAX and DOM. Strings and Streams are also supported.
> - Fine Grained data access,
>
>   - Result Sequences provide full XDM Data Type information about every result item.
> - Reading and writing data in any encoding, including UTF-8, UTF-16 and ISO-8859-1.

That way, so long as you write your queries to use standards-mandated functionality, your end users can retarget your application against another database -- be that eXist, BaseX, Oracle XDB, or something else.